# Copy a dynamically created variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to generalize the names of models in my code.

I have created a parent controller that that automatically loads a model that matches the controller class name.

However, when the model is loaded, it has the name of the model. ex;
`$this->load->model('some_model') creates $this->some_model`

What I would like to do is create the variable $this->model that would replace the `$this->some_model`.

I would rather not change the core code, so I am hoping there is some PHP solution I can use in my parent controller.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
$this->load->model($model_name);
$this->model = ${ $model_name };
```

This returns a `$this->model_name undefined` error.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading function:
>
> ```
> $this->load->model('Model_name', 'fubar');
> $this->fubar->function();
> ```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#what

Comment: i think you've got the hang of it, but this might be useful as well: http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/11/the-naming-of-things-writing-more-dynamic-code